# get 2 array unique and duplicate elements from parent array

Tags: javascript

```js
let array=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]:
```

I want to get 2 array of unique and duplicate elements: duplicate element's array1:`[1,4,5,6]` unique element's array2:`[2,3,7,8]`

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you can create a freq map and then you can essentially create an `Array` from that map then filter out the counts greater than 1 and less than 1.

```js
let array=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]

const returnUniqueAndDuplicateElements = (arr) => {
  let freqMap = {};
  for(const idx in arr){
    let number = arr[idx];
    if(!freqMap[number]){
      freqMap[number]=0;
    }
    freqMap[number]++;
  }
  const entries = Object.entries(freqMap);
  return {
    unique: entries.filter(([, freq]) => freq <= 1).map(item => Number(item[0])),
    duplicates: entries.filter(([, freq]) => freq > 1).map(item => Number(item[0]))
  }
}

console.log(returnUniqueAndDuplicateElements(array))
```

Comment: Why are you converting each element from the array to string values?  I don't think that was part of the requirement. He's using numbers NOT strings

Comment: So they were strings because they were keys on the object. I just casted them to numbers.

Comment: so now, why are you filtering the same data twice and using a map twice in order to have your function return an object? You're repeating yourself instead of just simply using a forEach to do a single loop.

Comment: Just add this to your code and the result will be the same without having to use the filter and map methods twice. const entries = Object.entries(freqMap);
  var unique = [];
  var duplicates = [];
  entries.forEach(function([_ , freq]) {
   if(freq <= 1){
     unique.push(+_);
   }else{
     duplicates.push(+_);
   }
  });

  return {
   unique,
   duplicates
  }

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a map to filter out duplicates. Here's a working solution.

```js
let arr= [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8];

function uniqueAndDuplicates() {
    var obj = {};
    var duplicates = [];
    var noDup = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(!obj[arr[i]]){
            obj[arr[i]] = 1;
            noDup.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            duplicates.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    var unique = noDup.filter(function(item, index){
        if(!duplicates.includes(noDup[index])){
            return noDup[index];
        }
    });

    return {
        unique,
        duplicates
    }
}

console.log(uniqueAndDuplicates(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding my solution since there is none with JS sets[[?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)] just yet:

```js
function uniqueAndDuplicate(arrayOfNumbers) {
  const unique = new Set();
  const duplicate = new Set();
  arrayOfNumbers.forEach((elem) => {
    if (unique.has(elem)) {
      unique.delete(elem);
      duplicate.add(elem);
    } else if (!duplicate.has(elem)) {
      unique.add(elem);
    }
  });
  return {
    unique: [...unique],
    duplicate: [...duplicate],
  };
}

console.log(uniqueAndDuplicate([1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]));
```